# Pokemon go with android doesn't let me even log in

Tags: pokemon-go

I have two options to log in with Google or trainer club. I choose Google and then nothing happens. Screen is with spinning poke ball in the middle of the screen and nothing. Tried reinstalling clearing cache even made full restore to factory setting. I'm on Samsung Galaxy Note 4 910T.
edit
I created trainer club account and I still cannot connect even log in...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are server issues, wait for a few hours then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It's server overload. I've had same issue before, last today at ~9AM UTC.

Comment: And I have constantly gps signal not found. And I tried everything in the Internet to make it working. What should I do now?